# Adding errai-security breaks GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, errai

When I add these to our app:

```
    <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.security.Security" />
    <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.security.SecurityShared" />
```

When I run the app:

```
[ERROR] Caused by: org.jboss.errai.bus.server.QueueUnavailableException: no queue available to send. (queue or session may have expired): (session id: 163fafa6e38d4f7d9f71e630cf9d4ca486863db58a3f5298b813e62ba0a64630)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.ServerMessageBusImpl.getQueueByMessage(ServerMessageBusImpl.java:872)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.ServerMessageBusImpl.send(ServerMessageBusImpl.java:334)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.bus.client.api.base.ConversationMessageWrapper.sendNowWith(ConversationMessageWrapper.java:238)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.bus.client.api.base.DefaultMessageBuilder$1.sendNowWith(DefaultMessageBuilder.java:84)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.bus.client.util.ErrorHelper.disconnectRemoteBus(ErrorHelper.java:171)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.bus.client.util.ErrorHelper.handleMessageDeliveryFailure(ErrorHelper.java:222)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.SimpleDispatcher.dispatch(SimpleDispatcher.java:63)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.bus.client.api.base.DefaultMessageBuilder$1.reply(DefaultMessageBuilder.java:140)
[ERROR]     ... 35 more
```

But when the inherits was removed teh app works fine. Why is adding those inherits break the app?